# Performance Testing Tools for Mobile Applications

Tags: android, ios, testing, performance-testing, android-testing

I am testing the application on Android & iOS platforms. The application uses the device mic. Network usage is used persistent.

Can any one suggest a simple Performance Testing tool to test the following,

1. I need to monitor & analyse the ***Network Usage***
2. I need to analyse the ***Battery Consumption***
3. Need to list down the scenarios when ***Memory Loss*** occurs

Generating the reports for the above mentioned scenarios would be much appreciated.

Comment: i don't know about android but you can test your app in instrument tool which installed with xcode automatically.

Comment: thanks sanjeet, but I need a single tool to analyze in both platforms.

Answer (score 1):

For battery consumption monitoring on Android you can use [Battery Historian](https://github.com/google/battery-historian).
It provides detailed information, uses JavaScript visualization libraries to display battery related events on a timeline with panning and zooming functionality

Answer (score 0):

- You should be using [AT&Ts ARO](https://developer.att.com/application-resource-optimizer) tool for deep **network usage
  analysis**
- You should be using [Battery Historian](https://github.com/google/battery-historian) for analysis of
  **Battery usage**
- You need to [leverage a set of tools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P--rg1o7Cz4&index=32&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE) to find the right Memory Loss scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Its been an old post but thought I shall mention the tools that I have been using:

- mAutomate (They have been providing lots of performance graphs for memory/CPU/Network etc)
- Robotium (I had to write hell lot of code for it :) & was not automated)

I have used these tools for Android Test automation. mAutomate works for iOS too ,not sure about Robotium.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at latest native [Android Studio Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler). It contains necessary tools for your purposes and they are often upgraded. Also for working with network I would like you to recommend [Charles Proxy](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Charles%20Proxy&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)